# Unable to ssh with error Connection Refused

Tags: ssh

I seem to be running into a problem when attempting to ssh. Here is my scenario;

```
Host A - 192.168.1.6
Host B - 192.168.5.10
```

From Host B, I am unable to ssh to Host A, as I get the error

```
"ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.6 port 22: Connection timed out".
```

However, what is weird is that I am able to ssh to any other hosts from Host B to any host on the Host A subnet except for Host B's IP.

I ran the

```
"ssh -vvv Host A" from Host B
```

and then on Host A I ran the "netstat -nat |grep 22" this is the output as I see the sync_recv, but never gets established.

```
netstat -nat |grep 22
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.6:22          192.168.5.10:58882      SYN_RECV
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.6:22          192.168.1.32:41564      ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.6:22          192.168.2.132:63086     ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN
```

Is there something that could be blocking it? I have firewall turned off on both ends.

Comment: please look in /var/log/auth.log (and other log files) on Host A.  You may see a useful ssh error in there, usually something like "Illegal user" or "Failed password" or something similar.

Comment: Starting simple, can you ping the host you wish to access?

Comment: looks like that host B never received the ACK, the first guess is that the router/routing table or iptables has some wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you need to input the user if you have login as root disabled like this : User@192.168.1.6

Comment: Olaf, Thanks for the response. However, even though i put int he user, i am still not able to connect. I ran a ssh -vv and it hangs here.. <pre>  ssh -vv user@192.168.1.6
OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.0-fips 29 Mar 2010
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.1.6 [192.168.1.6] port 22.</pre>

Comment: Hmm seems like there's no response from host. As far as i can tell of course. You could of course check if it hasn't crashed on the server but you probably did it already ;P Im going to think and if i come up with anything i'll post it here :)

Comment: Olaf,Thanks as I have been troubleshooting this for the past two days and can't seem to figure it out. I also did nmap and it shows port 22 opened.

Comment: This is on the other end when I run netstat while attempting to ssh. tcp        0      0 192.168.1.6:22          192.168.5.10:58926      SYN_RECV

Comment: When the error is "Connection timed out," the SSH server is never seeing the login attempt, so it's not due to a wrong username (or password).

Comment: Eliah, unfortunately its not "Connection Timed Out" but is "Connection Refused". Firewall's are turned off and no ACL on the router to prevent it as I can ssh to any other machine except that one in particular. - Thanks

Comment: The only think i could come up is purging both ssh on both computers. If that wont work then i have no idea.

Comment: @sohk220 *Connection refused* also means it has nothing to do with the username and password. That means the port appeared closed and no communication with the SSH server took place.

Comment: @Eliah it depends on the version i think as if i didnt input the user my ssh server would refuse the connection and the exact same error appeared.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

- Ping the server to see if you get any response.
- Make sure you have installed `sudo apt install openssh-server` on the server side.
- Try editing `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` and make sure you have:

  - `PasswordAuthentication yes`
  - Try selecting a different port, other than `Port 22`, then try `ssh -p <port> <user>@<server>`
  - Enable the port on your firewall `sudo ufw allow <port>`
  - You need to restart ssh after the changes `sudo systemctl restart ssh`
- Make sure again that ssh is enabled in the firewall `sudo ufw allow ssh`